# Find lists in a list that contains two specific elements

Tags: python, list

I have a list that contains many lists with a fixed number of elements:

```
info = [['N', 100, 'A'], ['O', 99, 'A'], ['C', 105, 'A'], ...]
```

I want to find the index of the element that contains `'N'` and `100`, namely `0`. I tried something like this to get the element itself:

```
matches = [a for name in a[2] and resnum in a[5] for a in info]
```

which didn't work. Is there a way to do this with list comprehensions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`next()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#next) and [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
>>> next(i for i, (a, b, _) in enumerate(info) if a == 'N' and b == 100)
0
>>> next(i for i, (a, b, _) in enumerate(info) if a == 'C' and b == 105)
2
```

Note that `next()` would throw a `StopIteration` exception if there is no match - you can either handle it with `try/except` or provide a *default value*, say, -1:

```
>>> next((i for i, (a, b, _) in enumerate(info) if a == 'invalid' and b == 0), -1)
-1
```

`_` is a canonical way to name the [throwaway variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5893163/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-single-underscore-variable-in-python) (we don't need the third values of the sublists in this particular case).

Comment: Is there a way to modify this to handle cases with more than one match?

Comment: @sodiumnitrate sure, just use the list comprehension: `[i for i, (a, b, _) in enumerate(info) if a == 'N' and b == 100]`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to fix your list comprehension, this should do:

```
>>> [info.index(x) for x in info if x[0]=='N' and x[1]==100]
[0]
```